# Converting date string to UTC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra

I want to convert a date stored as a `String` to `UTC`.

`String date = "Fri Aug 19 22:30:00 IST 2019"` (that I am fetching from Cassandra). 
How do you convert it to this format? `"2019-08-19T17:00:00+00:00"`

Comment: Use the `java.time` and `java.time.format` packages. Parse the date, then reformat it. Note that shorthand forms like `IST` may get you the wrong time zone, as `IST` can be India Standard Time, Israel Standard Time, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, below code works for the conversion and prints `2019-04-01T11:05:30Z[GMT]`

```
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
    val dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Mon, 1 Apr 2019 11:05:30 GMT", formatter)
    println(dateTime)
```

If the zone `IST` is predefined, you can also do a little bit manipulation in the string and remove that zone, and do as below, which also will print `2019-08-19T17:00Z[GMT]`

```
    val str = "Mon Aug 19 22:30:00 2019"
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy")
    val dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter)
    val zdtAtAsia = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
    val zdtAtGmt = zdtAtAsia.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
```

(Example is in kotlin. But it uses the same libraries as java)

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Test
  void test() {
    String date = "Mon Aug 19 22:30:00 IST 2019";
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    ZonedDateTime formatDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter)
                                                .withZoneSameLocal(
                                                    ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    System.out.println(formatDateTime);
  }

// Output: 2019-08-19T22:30Z[UTC]

The date mentioned in the post is wrong and it will end up in 
"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Fri Aug 19 22:30:00 IST 2019' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 1 differs from DayOfWeek 5 derived from 2019-08-19"
```